# Docker Nginx image with static content from an external volume - permissions issue

Tags: macos, nginx, docker

When I run an Nginx container with static content from an external volume, I get a 'forbidden' issue.

It's stated that Docker maintains ownership of the host when using a volume
so on my local OS X host, user/group is `myself:staff`, whereas Nginx container is expecting `www-data:www-data`.

On a Linux system, it would be easy to change the permissions of the host site directory with:

chown -R www-data:www-data /some/content

And if the `www-data` user/group is not present, I could create it with:

sudo groupadd www-data -g 33
   sudo useradd -u 33  --no-create-home --system --no-user-group www-data
   sudo usermod -g www-data www-data

But On OS X I can't. What the is the solution to change the user/group permissions on my OS X host to get it running in the container?

Answer (score 0):

The permission issue was not due to user/group settings.  The config files on the host must be executable !